# C# Unit Testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, testing

I'm implementing the following tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index_Get_RetrievesAllContributionsFromRepository()
{
    // Arrange
    Contributions Contribution1 = GetContributionNamed("Council", 2003);
    Contributions Contribution2 = GetContributionNamed("Council", 2004);

    InMemoryContributionRepository repository = new InMemoryContributionRepository();
    repository.Add(Contribution1);
    repository.Add(Contribution2);
    var controller = GetHomeController(repository);

    // Act
    var result = controller.Index();

    // Assert
    var model = (IEnumerable<Contributions>)result.ViewData.Model;
    CollectionAssert.Contains(model.ToList(), Contribution1);
    CollectionAssert.Contains(model.ToList(), Contribution2);
    CollectionAssert.xxxxxx(model.ToList().Count, Contribution1, 2);
}
```

The last test there with the xxxxxx is trying to check if `Contribution1` has 2 values, which it does. What line of code performs that test please?

c# novice

Comment: There are 3 parameters. You you explained 2. What does model.ToList().Count mean in that line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
Assert.AreEqual(2, model.Count());
```

But it sounds like you'd be *better* using:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new[] { Contribution1, Contribution2 },
                               model.ToList());
```

... That can replace all three of your lines.

In both cases note that the *expected* value should be the first argument, and the *actual* value should be the second.

Answer (score 1):

```
Assert.AreEqual(model.ToList().Count, 2);
```